# Blank Pages on Channel Field Edit

Tags: blank-screen

I just updated to EE 2.8 & MSM 2.1.6 and now when I try to edit a channel field, I get a blank page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a blank page or the field page without the setting, if it is a blank page try to enable $config['debug'] in your config.php & admin.php , system/index.php to see what happened there.

Answer (score 1):

I had moved over safecracker_file in the third_party directory along with my other extensions when doing the upgrade. Removing safecracker_file fixed the issue.